# R Plotly Bar Chart - Add horizontal line markers

Tags: r, plotly

I want to draw a bar chart with two bars side by side for each category (`LETTERS`) and add a horizontal line to each bar (`y_ref` as red lines & `z_ref` as green lines). It should look like this:

[image]

I tried it with add_trace (and add_lines, add_segment, etc) but can't find the correct way to make it work. Here's one of the reprex's I tried so far.

```
df <- tibble(x = LETTERS[1:5], y = runif(5), z = runif(5), y_ref = runif(5), z_ref = runif(5))

plot_ly(
  df,
  x = ~x,
  y = ~y,
  type = "bar",
  name = "a"
) %>% add_trace(
  y = ~z, 
  name = "b"
) %>% layout(
  legend = list(
    orientation = "h"
  )
) %>% add_trace(
  y = ~y_ref, 
  type = 'scatter', 
  mode = 'lines',
  marker = list(
    line = list(
      width = 2,
      color = "red"
    )
  )
) %>% add_trace(
  y = ~z_ref, 
  type = 'scatter', 
  mode = 'lines',
  marker = list(
    line = list(
      width = 2,
      color = "green"
    )
  )
)
```

Edit: I need a solution for `n` bars.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have to use `shapes` for line segments in Plotly. Additionally, because the x-axis is discrete, the `x` for the shapes will need to be in `paper` space.

When working in paper space, you use the plot `domain` to figure out the values for `x`. Plotly has a default `domain` set to [0, 1] for both `x` and `y` axes.

There is a gap between bars; that has to be accounted for as well. I used three functions to create the line segments, using all of this information.

Lastly, I used a `seed` for repeatability.

Libraries, seed, and base plot

```
library(tidyverse)
library(plotly)

set.seed(8)
df <- tibble(x = LETTERS[1:5], y = runif(5), z = runif(5),
             y_ref = runif(5), z_ref = runif(5))

p = plot_ly(df, x = ~x, y = ~y,
        type = "bar", name = "a") %>% 
  add_trace(y = ~z, name = "b")
```

Create the segments

```
# standard shape elements, call for color
details <- function(col){
  list(type = 'line',
       line = list(color = col),
       xref = "paper", yref = "y")
}
# green lines for orange bars
segs = lapply(1:nrow(df),
              function(k){
                x1 <- (k + k)/10 - .02  # if the domain is [0, 1]
                x0 <- x1 - .08
                y0 <- y1 <- df[k, ]$z_ref
                line = list("x0" = x0, "x1" = x1,
                            "y0" = y0, "y1" = y1)
                deets = details("green")
                c(deets, line)
              })
# green lines for blue bars
segs2 = lapply(1:nrow(df),
               function(j){
                 x1 <- (j + j - 1)/10  # if the domain is [0, 1]
                 x0 <- x1 - .08
                 y0 <- y1 <- df[j, ]$y_ref
                 line = list("x0" = x0, "x1" = x1,
                             "y0" = y0, "y1" = y1)
                 deets = details("red")
                 c(deets, line)
               })
segs = append(segs, segs2)
```

Put it together

```
p %>% layout(legend = list(orientation = "h"),
             shapes = segs)
```

[image]

Comment: I assume you mean a different number of `shapes`? If so, definitely. They aren't actually tied to a column; they're just rendered that way in this answer.

Comment: Yeah, I just figured it out. On the right it's `x1 = (k + k)/(2*n) - (1/(10*n))` and `x0 = (1/(2.5*n))`, on the left it's `x1 = (j + j - 1)/(2*n)` and `x0 = x1 - (1/(2.5*n))`. (Btw, I accidentally deleted my previous comment, where I asked for a general solution for n bars).